# Creating a stacked and dodge bar plot over a numeric x variable using fill with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I am using ggplot2 in R and am trying to create a stacked bar plot on the y-axis to show a continuous numeric variable (var1: 1, 2, 3...) with fill categories on a categorical variable (var2: A, B, C) over a continuous numeric x-axis variable (var3: 1, 2, 3...). However I would also like to separate by another categorical variable (var4: L1, L2, L3) per each x-axis variable.

For example I am easily able to create either of these via position 'stack' ([Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpxxp.png)) or 'dodge' ([Dodge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4thY.png)) respectively (see below) but I would like them combined. Ideally the colours on the stacks are consistent and the dodge is outlined or I would even just label them manually if necessary.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 #Data
 set.seed(3)
 data = data.frame(var1 = 1:15, 
              var2 = sample(c("A","B","C"),15, replace=TRUE),
              var3 = sample(c("1","2","3","4","5"), 15, replace=TRUE),
              var4 = sample(c("L1","L2","L3"), 15, replace=TRUE))
 #Stack
 ggplot(data, aes(x=as.numeric(var3), y=var1, fill=var2))+ 
       geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="stack")+ 
       theme(legend.position="right")+
       labs(title="Stack")+
       theme_bw()
 #Dodge
 ggplot(data, aes(x=as.numeric(var3), y=var1, fill=var4))+ 
       geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="dodge")+ 
       theme(legend.position="right")+
       labs(title="Dodge")+
       theme_bw()
 #Facet
 ggplot(data, aes(x=as.numeric(var3), y=var1, fill=var2))+ 
       geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="stack")+ 
       theme(legend.position="right")+
       labs(title="Facet")+
       theme_bw()+
       facet_wrap(~var4)
```

I am aware of faceting ([Facet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dNOg.png)) and know it to be a common solution and have done that as well. However I would really like to do both at the same time such that there is a single plot (y vs x) with stacked and adjacent bar plots. It seems pointless here but I have a much larger dataset such that there are values and combinations of var2, var3, and var4. If this is impossible I will rely on faceting but it seems like something that should be possible.